# Drupal 6 absolute wildcards in _menu(), is it possible?

Tags: drupal, drupal-routes

is it possible to handle all wildcards in _menu() by module.

I know about specific wildcards like

`display/page/%` 
but that won't work for paths `display/page/3/andOrderBy/Name`

what If I want to handle unpredicted ammount of parameters like

`display/page/3/12/45_2/candy/yellow/bmw/turbo`

I want to have one `display/*` _menu() path to handle all ARGUMENTS.

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal will pass any additional URL elements as additional parameters to your `hook_menu` callback function - use [func_get_args()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) in your callback to get them.

So if you register only one wildcard `display/page/%`, but the actual request has two additional elements `display/page/3/andOrderBy/Name`, your callback will be passed '3' as an explicit parameter, but also 'andOrderBy' and 'Name' as implicit additional ones.

Example callback:

```
function yourModuleName_display_callback($page_number) {
  // Grab additional arguments
  $additional_args = func_get_args();
  // Remove first one, as we already got it explicitely as $page_number
  array_shift($additional_args);
  // Check for additional args
  if (!empty($additional_args)) {
    // Do something with the other arguments ...
  }
  // other stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ah ;)
you were right

here is how i solved it.

```
function mysearch_menu() {
$items['mysearch/%'] = array(
'page callback' => 'FN_search',
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
}


function FN_search()
{
    return print_r(func_get_args(),true);
};
```

Comment: BTW, it is standard practice in Drupal to prefix all your functions with your modules name to prevent naming conflicts, so if your module is called 'mysearch', your callback should be named `mysearch_search` or `mysearch_FN_search`. Otherwise adding a new module to an existing instance might break the site.